# C Array Allocation in a Loop For Threading

Tags: c, arrays, optimization, compiler-construction

## The Motivation

I'm attempting to save various environments via `setjmp` for the purpose of jumping back to them later and calling functions and making sure that the stack frames run into each other. For Example:

env[0] stack:

```
----------
|  text  |
----------
|  data  |
----------
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|  ~~~~  |
----------
```

where the tildes represent the stack frames of main etc.

env[1] stack:

```
----------
|  text  |
----------
|  data  |
----------
|        |
|        |
|        |
|  ****  |
|  ****  |
|  ****  |
|  ****  |
|  ~~~~  |
----------
```

Where the stars represent a large array I've allocated.

The idea is that if I `longjmp` to `env[0]` and start running some methods, then `longjmp` to `env[1]` and start running some methods, the stack frames of `env[0]` will start to fill up the empty space in that array, and the stack frames of `env[1]` will be on top of that array, and not overwrite the stack frames of `env[0]`. Basic threading.

I'd also like to have more than just two threads, in fact, I'd like MAXTHREADS. Intuitively it works like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < MAXTHREADS; i++) {
    char c[STACKSIZE];
    if( setjmp(env[i]) != 0 ) {
        /* Stuff that thread i will do goes here */
    }
}
```

### Test 1

However, as you can clearly see in the following test program, each c array started at the same spot on the stack, defeating the purpose.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    char c[10];
    printf("On Iteration %d array starts at %x and goes to %x\n",i,c,c+10);
}
```

Outputs:

```
On Iteration 0 array starts at ffbfef02 and goes to ffbfef0c
On Iteration 1 array starts at ffbfef02 and goes to ffbfef0c
On Iteration 2 array starts at ffbfef02 and goes to ffbfef0c
On Iteration 3 array starts at ffbfef02 and goes to ffbfef0c
On Iteration 4 array starts at ffbfef02 and goes to ffbfef0c
On Iteration 5 array starts at ffbfef02 and goes to ffbfef0c
On Iteration 6 array starts at ffbfef02 and goes to ffbfef0c
On Iteration 7 array starts at ffbfef02 and goes to ffbfef0c
On Iteration 8 array starts at ffbfef02 and goes to ffbfef0c
On Iteration 9 array starts at ffbfef02 and goes to ffbfef0c
```

This makes sense for a multitude of reasons, scope dictates that the c array ceases to exist at the end of the loop, additionally the compiler probably moves it outside of the loop because the size is static.

**Test 1 gave me the size I want, but not the allocation I want**

### Test 2

So my next thought was to allocate an array of STACKSIZE * i, so that even though the arrays each started at the same spot, they would be bigger each time and push up my stack pointer far enough when the time came to switch to that environment. Here's the test:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    char c[10 * i];
    printf("On Iteration %d array starts at %u and goes to %u\n",i,c,c+(10*i));
    //note: switched from %x to %u to make comparison mentally simpler
}
```

However, this outputs

```
On Iteration 0 array starts at 4290768760 and goes to 4290768760
On Iteration 1 array starts at 4290768744 and goes to 4290768754
On Iteration 2 array starts at 4290768720 and goes to 4290768740
On Iteration 3 array starts at 4290768688 and goes to 4290768718
On Iteration 4 array starts at 4290768648 and goes to 4290768688
On Iteration 5 array starts at 4290768592 and goes to 4290768642
On Iteration 6 array starts at 4290768528 and goes to 4290768588
On Iteration 7 array starts at 4290768456 and goes to 4290768526
On Iteration 8 array starts at 4290768376 and goes to 4290768456
On Iteration 9 array starts at 4290768280 and goes to 4290768370
```

It's a little hard to see at first, but due to the large numbers, you can focus on only the last three digits.

The first array goes from *760* to *760* -- fine, it's for i = 0

The second array goes from *744* to *754* -- fine, we moved a bit, but it's an array of size 10 in the general position that we want it in

The third array goes from *720* to *740* -- uh-oh, the array didn't start in the same spot as the others, and it's double the size.

To Illustrate the pattern on the stack, each * represents 10 chars in an array, and gaps between chunks of stars are the gaps between the arrays:

```
*
*
*

*
*

*
~
```

The tilde is the main,etc as before.

The pattern goes on. This is likely machine dependent, but my machine is allocating the arrays in order, rather than going back down the bottom each time as it did with constant size arrays.

**Test 2 gave me the allocation I want, but sizes WAY larger than I'd like.**

### Test 3

Now having learned that my machine will allocate arrays overwriting each other if they're the same size, but stacked on top of each other if they vary in size, I thought that maybe I could allocate `STACKSIZE + i` instead of `STACKSIZE * i` of each. I ran this experiment:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    char c[10+i];
    printf("On Iteration %d array starts at %u and goes to %u\n",i,c,c+10+i);
}
```

Which outputs:

```
On Iteration 0 array starts at 4290768808 and goes to 4290768818
On Iteration 1 array starts at 4290768792 and goes to 4290768803
On Iteration 2 array starts at 4290768776 and goes to 4290768788
On Iteration 3 array starts at 4290768760 and goes to 4290768773
On Iteration 4 array starts at 4290768744 and goes to 4290768758
On Iteration 5 array starts at 4290768728 and goes to 4290768743
On Iteration 6 array starts at 4290768712 and goes to 4290768728
On Iteration 7 array starts at 4290768688 and goes to 4290768705
On Iteration 8 array starts at 4290768664 and goes to 4290768682
On Iteration 9 array starts at 4290768640 and goes to 4290768659
```

After analysis, it's using the same allocation behavior I expected.

**Test 3 gave me the allocation I want, and sizes close to what I want, but still not perfect**

## The Question

So Test 3's strategy could work in my original code up top, allocate MAXTHREADS arrays of STACKSIZE + i, saving the env between each, but it seems suboptimal. I'm allocating extra space in each array simply to trick my compiler.

Is there a better way to do this? Some other trick to make the compiler allocate fresh arrays of STACKSIZE each time?

**How do I get the allocation of tests 2 and 3, with the size of test 1?**

Comment: You could maybe mark the array `volatile`? Then the compiler shouldn't touch it for optimization.

Comment: No effect. Tried it with the first test code, changed to `volatile char c[10]`, same output.

Comment: You seem to believe that you are entitled to a "stack". Given the features added by the C11 standard, I believe a "graph" might be more suitable for the storage of objects with automatic storage duration.

Comment: I just woke up so still am a little dizzy, but of course using `volatile` wouldn't work... The compiler would probably still reuse the same stack space inside the loop.

Comment: I suppose an inline `asm` is out of the question =(

Comment: Inline `asm` certainly wouldn't be C.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this:

```
jmp_buf states[NUMTHREADS]
char stacks[NUMTHREADS][STACKSIZE];
// your scheduler starts *after* this!
for(;;) {
    // setjmp to remember the current thread's state
    // longjmp to thread i+1 and use stacks[i+1][top]
}
```

Comment: I could do that, but then I can't save the environment between each allocation. The array is a dummy array, I'm not actually putting anything in it, just using it as a mechanism to move the stack pointer before spawning threads.

Comment: I can't to any `longjmp`ing yet, as I haven't `setjmp` yet. This is where I'm doing my `setjmp`ing, ie allocate array, setjmp, allocate array, setjmp, etc. I guess I should clarify that I'm in the initialization method now, setting up before any threads have been spawned by the user.

Comment: You cannot move the stackpointer by having an array in the loop: In the next loop-iteration the stack will have forgotten about the "previous iteration's array"

Comment: Run the second test code though, allocation an array of size (10 + i) moved up the stack by >= (10 + i) each time.

Comment: If that is so then it is machine-dependent, it is not standard however. The standard says that outside of the single iteration of the loop the array does not exist anymore.

Comment: longjmp to thread i+1 and "use stacks[i+1][top] doesn't make stack frames from methods called by thread i+1 magically appear in the middle of that array...

Comment: Of course it does not. Since you dont want to use assembly (to manipulate the stack-pointer) you have to copy the stack-memory to the real stack before calling longjmp and store the previous stack's memory to its array when yielding from the thread!

Comment: So you're suggesting that every time I switch between environments, I should save my entire runtime stack to these arrays, and then restore each time?

Comment: Not the whole thread-stacks of course, just the parts they are actually using: the part between *their* stack-pointer and the stackpointer of the scheduler. But yes you have to copy the memory if you dont want to use assembly (change the stackpointer).

Comment: That sounds horribly inefficient compared to what I described up top.

Comment: If efficiency is your concern then you should not try to do a cooperative scheduler of many logical threads within one real thread at all. You should use *real* (as in "OS supported", preemptive etc) threads.

Comment: Yes, of course that would be more efficient, but it wouldn't answer my question, which, when it comes down to it, is how to allocate N arrays of size X on the stack in order, executing some instruction between each allocation.

Comment: You cannot. If *that* were possible with just C then someone would have posted it. You can either use real threads or use the copying-trick.

Comment: The STACKSPACE + i solution works perfectly, and I currently have it implemented and working. It's just not optimal as for a large number of threads, we'd be adding a lot of space.

Comment: It will not work on other systems, there is no requirement in the C standard that arrays that are no-longer in scope still exist!

Comment: It doesn't have to work on other systems, it has to work on this system. And the arrays don't exist, the new arrays are just after where the old one was in memory.